# Как настроить метод авторизации в Samba 3.5.6 по файлу-базе виртуальных пользователей?

Tags: samba, linux

Как заставить (может быть с помощью какого-нибудь хитрого патча) Samba server 3.5 работать по отдельной базе пользователей и паролей, без использования заведенных в системе, а также без использования отдельного LDAP для этого.

Я точно знаю, что данное возможно, но утилиты smbpasswd и pbdedit требуют обязательного наличия пользователя Nix системы или связи с LDAP-сервером, для поиска этих пользователей.

Answer (score 1):

Это не возможно тк права на доступ самба берет от локальных пользователей. Вы можете отключить пользователям вход в систему локально.